# Swiper js with Alpine js

Tags: javascript, vite, swiper.js, alpine.js

I'm using a code from codepen(https://codepen.io/m-eckel/pen/oNxeVgp) to create a carousel with Swiper js and Alpine js. but the code is not working in my localhost! this is my `index.html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vite App</title>
</head>

<body class="bg-[#f9f9f9] font-shabnam">

  <div x-data="{swiper: null}" x-init="swiper = new Swiper($refs.container, {
      loop: true,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 0,
  
      breakpoints: {
        640: {
          slidesPerView: 1,
          spaceBetween: 0,
        },
        768: {
          slidesPerView: 2,
          spaceBetween: 0,
        },
        1024: {
          slidesPerView: 3,
          spaceBetween: 0,
        },
      },
    })" class="relative w-10/12 mx-auto flex flex-row">
    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 z-10 flex items-center">
      <button @click="swiper.slidePrev()"
        class="bg-white -ml-2 lg:-ml-4 flex justify-center items-center w-10 h-10 rounded-full shadow focus:outline-none">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="chevron-left w-6 h-6">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M12.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414L9.414 10l3.293 3.293a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414l4-4a1 1 0 011.414 0z"
            clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-container" x-ref="container">
      <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <!-- Slides -->
        <div class="swiper-slide p-4">
          <div class="flex flex-col rounded shadow overflow-hidden">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1496128858413-b36217c2ce36?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1679&q=80"
                alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide p-4">
          <div class="flex flex-col rounded shadow overflow-hidden">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598951092651-653c21f5d0b9?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80"
                alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="swiper-slide p-4">
          <div class="flex flex-col rounded shadow overflow-hidden">
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
              <img class="h-48 w-full object-cover"
                src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1598946423291-ce029c687a42?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=80"
                alt="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 z-10 flex items-center">
      <button @click="swiper.slideNext()"
        class="bg-white -mr-2 lg:-mr-4 flex justify-center items-center w-10 h-10 rounded-full shadow focus:outline-none">
        <svg viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" class="chevron-right w-6 h-6">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd"
            d="M7.293 14.707a1 1 0 010-1.414L10.586 10 7.293 6.707a1 1 0 011.414-1.414l4 4a1 1 0 010 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0z"
            clip-rule="evenodd"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and this is my `main.js` code:

```
import Alpine from "alpinejs";
import Swiper from "swiper";
import "./style.css";
import "swiper/css";

window.Alpine = Alpine;
window.Swiper = Swiper;

Alpine.start();
```

Why doesn't this work on my localhost but on codepen? Did I do something wrong? The code above only shows me the carousel and none of the carousel buttons work :( I would be grateful if someone could solve my problem and tell me what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
```

```
 <button class="swiper-button-next bg-white -ml-2 lg:-ml-4 flex justify-center items-center w-10 h-10 rounded-full shadow focus:outline-none">
```

```
 <button
        class="swiper-button-prev bg-white -mr-2 lg:-mr-4 flex justify-center items-center w-10 h-10 rounded-full shadow focus:outline-none">
```